# Why does my node.js HTTP requests fail when my server is initialized by my test suite?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, axios, mocha.js

I have been trying to write a test suite to my node.js API project and one of their requirements is to control when the server starts and stops. For that, I wrote this code below with two functions: `initializeWebServer` and `stopWebServer`.

**express.js**

```
const initializeWebServer = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app = express();

    /* some middlewares */

    app.use('/', userRoutes);

    httpServer = http.createServer(app);

    httpServer.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }

      resolve(app);
    });
  });
};

const stopWebServer = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    httpServer.close(() => { resolve(); });
  });
};
```

Using `mocha` to run my tests, I choose to manage my server connection with `before` and `after` hooks, using async/await syntax.

**user.spec.js**

```
let axiosAPIClient;

before(async () => {
  await initializeWebServer();
  const axiosConfig = {
    baseURL: `http://localhost:3000`,
    validateStatus: () => true
  };
  axiosAPIClient = axios.create(axiosConfig);
});

after(async () => {
  await stopWebServer();
});

describe('POST /api/user', () => {
it('when add a new user, then should get back approval with 200 response', async () => {
  const userData = {
    /* user props */
  };

  const response = await axiosAPIClient.post('/api/user', userData);

  expect(response).to.containSubset({
    status: 200,
    data: { message: 'User signed up.' }
  });
```

When `axios` (I tried `fetch` too) submit any HTTP request, `mocha` returns the following error: `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`. I tried to increase the timeout interval, but it didn't work.

If I execute my test suite without hooks, initializing my server with `nodemon` pointing to my index file with the same `await initializeWebServer();`, HTTP requests work as it should.

I really don't understand why this is happening, I think it's something with `mocha`.

Comment: Is it possible that it's the http request itself that's never completing?

Comment: If I put `--timeout 0` flag on mocha, it hangs eternally, blocking another requests too. When I began to write and run this test case, axios requests was working. Suddenly, this error occurred and I got stuck on this.

Comment: Your first step should be to find out exactly where it's hanging. Is it during the test? During cleanup? console.log is an easy way to get started (or hook up a real debugger)

Answer (score 0):

I did some debug tests and figured out that I forgot to set up a db connection when I run my test suite, including in `before` and `after` hooks. It was a simple mistake.

**user.spec.js**

```
let axiosAPIClient;

before(async () => {
  await initializeWebServer();
  db.setUp();

  /* axios config etc. */

after(async () => {
  await stopWebServer();
  await db.closeConnection();
});
```

Comment: Remove answer, or update your response with more details about how you fixed it.